# Cambiar donde escribe el log RollingFile log4j2

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

Necesito poder modificar la ubicacion donde escribe los archivos de log mi archivo de log4j2.xml .

Me gustaria crear una carpeta al mismo nivel que el .jar ( mi/ruta/app.jar )  de la aplicacion para guardar los logs ( mi/ruta/logs/log1.log ) .

El problema viene en que no consigo obtener desde donde se esta ejecutando mi jar ( que puede variar ) en el archivo ( no quiero setear variables de entorno en principio ) . ¿Como lo hariais ?
Este es mi archivo de log4j2.xml que ahora mismo tiene una ruta estatica /mi/ruta.

```xml
        <RollingFile name="rollingFile"
            fileName="mi/ruta/application.log"
            filePattern="mi/ruta/application.%d{dd-MMM}.log"
            ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <!-- Delete logs older than 60 days -->
                <Delete basePath="mi/ruta/">
                    <IfLastModified age="60d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
```

He visto que puedes usar incluso variables de spring [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup) pero no quiero implementar esa dependencia de cloud ( ya que no lo uso para nada )

Y dentro de la misma pregunta , si en el IfLastModified agrego el path de la carpeta , deberia de borrar los logs ( en este caso cada 60 dias , ¿ no ? )

Cualquier idea es bievenida , ¡ gracias !

Comment: Disculpa, no es muy clara la pregunta. Tienes una aplicación, aparentemente empaquetada como JAR, y quieres configurarle el file appender. ¿QUé quieres obtener exactamente?

Comment: Quiero que cree una carpeta al lado de donde se ejecuta el .jar ( por ejemplo opt/app/app.jar ) y cree ahi una carpeta (opt/app/logs/log1.log) pero ese path , no se como podria obtenerlo sin setearlo por una variable de entorno a la hora de desplegar , no se si hay alguna otra posibilidad vaya

Comment: Si usas una ruta relativa como `./logs/application.log`, ¿qué sucede?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes de cambiar la ruta de una ruta absoluta a una relativa utilizando punto, el punto representa el directorio donde se ejecuta el proyecto, si lo ejecutas con el IDE te creara la carpeta dentro de la carpeta del proyecto pero al ejecutar el `jar` la creara al mismo nivel del `jar`.

Por ejemplo si queremos que los logs se guarden dentro de una carpeta logs:

```
 fileName="./logs/application.log"
 filePattern="./logs/application.%d{dd-MMM}.log"
```